# Calling a Service with Async Await

Tags: c#, async-await

I am looking at using the `async` `await` keywords in a call to a Service, but wondered if the `await` keyword is needed?

Modifying an example if found; What I would like to do is setup an `async` call to a service that gets on with the job, but doesn't need to wait for a response:

```
async Task CallService(InformationForService informationForService)
{
    var service = SetupService();

    // Does this need the await keyword?
    service.Doof(informationForService);

}
```

Comment: what is returning `Task<int>`?

Comment: how your code get compiled?

Comment: Sorry was copying that from an example, I forgot I left that as the return.

Comment: you're asking if the method `Doof` needs the await keyword. Does it return `Task`? does it itself use the `await` keyword or `Task.Run()`? If so, then yes - it should probably be awaited.

Comment: @Default I am not too worried about a response. I want to `Doof` the service and then the application can forget about the call.

Comment: Is `Doof` asynchrouns? Does it return a `Task`?

Comment: @svick no, `Doof` is a method on the service it returns true or false, but I am not worried about getting a response back from the server, I just want to let the program call the service and get on with normal process without waiting.

Comment: This is likely something I will come back to once we get VS2012 working in development. could I ask people to vote up their favourite answer to help pick the best one and dont forget to vote up your friendly OP, who is a `dumb***`! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare your function as async and that it returns Task then something in your code needs to return that type. I don't see anything in your code that does because you're not using the await keyword that would normally yield from your function while the call is being sent to the service and then continue from the following line when the call to the service responds.

If you don't care what the service returns, ignore it, but use the await keyword because that will allow your code to get on with other work while the service call is completed.

```
async Task<int> CallService(InformationForService informationForService)
{
    var service = SetupService();

    // Does this need the await keyword?
    await service.Doof(informationForService);

}
```

Also, note that if you're calling a service using WCF, you can issue a one-way call that completes once the last byte of the message is sent. [Juval Lowy discusses one-way calls in this paper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx).

Comment: right so if the return if void then I still say `await service.Doof(x)`

Comment: @LukeDuddridge the method needs to return a `Task` to be awaitable.

Comment: @Default ok so it cannot be void. can it be just `Task` or does it need a return type?

Comment: The `Doof` function _should_ be prefixed with `Async` as to inform the user that it uses the `async Task` return value.

Comment: @LukeDuddridge `await Task` is equivalent with `void`. `await Task<T>` is equivalent with return value `T`.

Answer (score 1):

A method doesn't have to be `async` to be awaitable. There are many methods that return `Task` and can be used by `await`, even though they're not `async`.

I'm assuming that your service is a WCF service. In this case, if you (re-)generate a proxy using VS2012, for every method `Doof` on your service [you'll get a `DoofAsync` method that will work with `await`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/13/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-async-await.aspx).

Your `CallService` method does not need to be `async`; you can just return the `Task` that you get from `DoofAsync`:

```
Task CallService(InformationForService informationForService)
{
  var service = SetupService();
  return service.DoofAsync(informationForService);
}
```

Comment: @LukeDuddridge Your question said you're looking into `async`-`await`, so that's what Stephen's answer is about. And you can't reasonably use `async`-`await` from VS 2010.

Comment: @LukeDuddridge: I recommend you upgrade. I'm not aware of any showstopping issues from VS2010->VS2012; in fact it's one of the smoothest transitions.

Comment: @svick oh *!"£**£*"& sorry. completely blanked on the key issue that means I cannot use Async await! For some reason I thought I could... We will be stuck on VS2010 for now, we are only just getting Windows 7!